# Understanding and parsing HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE correctly

Tags: php, http

I was wondering how the string of `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is determined.
if a user has the following string:
`"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8"`

- how are these comma separated parameters determined (OS, browser, IP->geo?)
- what do those params mean?

SideQuestion: Is there any part of an HTTP request to get the OS language?

I went over google, but I couldn't understand the `q=n` quality value, please please, please don't copy google or PHP.NET, I can search and read also, I would like to understand and make the best of using the most of an http request.

Thanks,
Bud

Comment: The [quality value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Quality_values) denotes priority, with higher values sorting first. By your example, servers answering this request should attempt to provide English as a first choice, then Hebrew.

Comment: @AlexHowansky - thanks re quality value - how would that be changed, what determines this? Can you provide a full answer to my questions and i'll mark it as an answer? I just need to know what i'm parsing and if values are interchangable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, `Accept-Language` can be used in one of the following forms:

1. `Accept-Language: *`, which means you are ready to accept any language.
2. `Accept-Language: <language>`, where `<language>` stands for the language code, usually 2 letters.
3. `Accept-Language: <language-locale>`, where `<language-locale>` can be seen as an extended form of `<language>`,
4. A compound form, you have already given an example: `"en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8"`.

> how are these comma separated parameters determined (OS, browser, IP->geo?)

The default value is retrieved from OS language settings by the browser.

And users can manually set preferred language(s) from browser's settings panel. If multiple languages are set, their order being the order in `Accept-Language` as you see.

> what do those params mean?

They are a list of `<quality>-<language>` pairs, separated by `;`.

Default quality is 1, so your `Accept-Language` value actually is:

`q=1,en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8,rest of languages...`

> Is there any part of an HTTP request to get the OS language?

No.

> I couldn't understand the q=n quality value.

As explained.

Comment: Separated by "," not ";".

Comment: umm isnt @JulianReschke right? for example my own `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is `en-US,en;q=0.9`. from the reading i have done on this subject, it should be read as the quality of `en-US,en` being `0.9`, whereas no other languages and their corresponding quality values have been set

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Yuankun's answer re the 'q' values, looking at [RFC7231 section-5.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5) (which Obsoletes [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)) it seems that is not quite correct.

It should be `<language-range>;<quality>, ...` such that an example string

`en,en-US,en-AU;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4`

ends up as

- `en;q=1`
- `en-US;q=1`
- `en-AU;q=0.8`
- `fr;q=0.6`
- `en-GB;q=0.4`

Comment: You may want to cite RFC 7231, Section 5.3.5 instead.

Comment: @JulianReschke, thanks - done. I'd got that reference from elsewhere. Is there a good reference for what RFC relates / obsoletes other RFCs?  Fortunately the scheme had not been changed :)

Comment: This answer does not explain how to parse the string - do you only want to add that parts are divided by a comma?

Comment: The OP did not ask how to parse it (plenty of answers on that) he wished to understand what the string meant.  The commas separate each LANG;q pair except where there is no q specified so it is 1.

Comment: @JulianReschke are the values separated by the semicolon or comma? i know that the default `q` is 1, so `en,en-US,en-AU;q=0.8,fr;` could be read as both `q=1,en,en-US,en-AU; q=0.8,fr` and `en,en-US,en-AU;q=0.8, fr;q=0.6` but the latter obvs makes less sense

Comment: @BugWhisperer - it's all in the spec

Comment: @BugWhisperer, as it says above, each element is separated by a comma. If there is a specified value, the semicolon is used `<key>;<Value>,`. If there is no value specified, the default value is used (as in my example bullet points above).

Comment: ok, thats what i thought, but there are ppl elsewhere on SO saying that each "unit" so to speak is separated by a semi-colon as opposed to each "unit" being separated by a comma, which actually is more intuitive than this

Answer (score 1):

The string is determined by the client software. The client can request whatever languages it wants, with whatever priorities it wants. The server is not obliged to comply.

The rules that describe the format of the string can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language).

The [quality value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Quality_values) denotes priority, with higher values sorting first. By your example, servers answering this request should attempt to provide English as a first choice, then Hebrew.

You probably don't need to parse this yourself. You can likely use something like [locale_accept_from_http()](http://php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php).

Comment: `locale_accept_from_http()` is an "undefined function"